# "All goes" not "All go"?

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

Currently reading [**this article,**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/north-korea-could-start-war-043000981.html), the second paragraph says,

> As North Korea’s nuclear and ballistic missile programs have become more adventurous, a worrying possibility has begun to emerge. There’s a chance that—at some point—the North Koreans might want to combine the two testing programs, by putting a live nuclear warhead on top of a ballistic missile. **That means,** ***assuming*** ***all goes*** **as it should, the missile would fly downrange to its appointed target zone, and the warhead would detonate in the atmosphere.** That sort of test—an end-to-end test of the full weapon system—would be a convincing demonstration that Pyongyang had crossed the critical bridges: that it had a long-range ballistic missile with the throw-weight to carry a nuclear warhead, a warhead able to be placed atop the missile, and a re-entry vehicle that could survive the stresses of re-entry.

My research, by all go, as [**here**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all%20go) means "full of activities" or "very busy" (British informal).

I don't understand this sentence (painted by black and especially bold italic part "***assuming all goes.***")

Could you help me what "***assuming all goes***" mean, and the meaning of the sentence?

Thank you for your kind support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression **assuming all goes as it should** is equivalent to **if everything proceeds as intended** or **if everything works out as planned**.

Depending on how it is used, **all** can act as any of several parts of speech. In this case, **all** is acting as a singular noun and takes a singular verb.

If **all** were used to refer to a number of items or individuals, it would take the plural, as in:

> All (the plates) fell to the floor and were shattered.

You will find more illustrations and explanations of its use at:

http://partofspeech.org/what-part-of-speech-is-all/